# Joining data from three tables to populate another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table structures in my database

dbo.Customer:

<kbd>Customer_Pk</kbd><kbd>Customer_Name</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>                   <kbd>ACustomer</kbd>        

<kbd>2</kbd>                   <kbd>BCustomer</kbd>        

<kbd>3</kbd>                   <kbd>CCustomer</kbd>

dbo.Import

<kbd>AProduct</kbd>      <kbd>BProduct</kbd>        <kbd>CProduct</kbd>

<kbd>ACustomer</kbd>  <kbd>Sale Value1</kbd> <kbd>Sale Value2</kbd>    <kbd>SaleValue3</kbd>

<kbd>BCustomer</kbd>  <kbd>Sale Value4</kbd> <kbd>Sale Value5</kbd>    <kbd>SaleValue6</kbd>

<kbd>CCustomer</kbd>  <kbd>Sale Value7</kbd> <kbd>Sale Value8</kbd>    <kbd>SaleValue9</kbd>

dbo.Product:

<kbd>Product_Pk</kbd>   <kbd>Product_Name</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>                   <kbd>AProduct</kbd>        

<kbd>2</kbd>                   <kbd>BProduct</kbd>        

<kbd>3</kbd>                   <kbd>CProduct</kbd>

which I need to join to populate the table dbo.Cost (the reason I have a separate cost table is because the same product may have different costs for different customers)

dbo.cost:

<kbd>Cost_PK</kbd> <kbd>Cost_Value</kbd><kbd>Customer_FK</kbd><kbd>Product_FK</kbd>

<kbd>Cell 1</kbd>      <kbd>Cell 2</kbd>          <kbd>Cell 3</kbd>             <kbd>Cell 4</kbd>          

<kbd>Cell 5</kbd>      <kbd>Cell 6</kbd>          <kbd>Cell 7</kbd>             <kbd>Cell 8</kbd>          

<kbd>Cell 9</kbd>      <kbd>Cell 10</kbd>        <kbd>Cell 11</kbd>           <kbd>Cell 12</kbd>

So the table dbo.Cost needs to describe which customers own which products and how much they paid.

Edit: SQL create scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
[Customer_PK] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Customer_Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Customer_PK] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,  ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [Product_PK] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Product_Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Product_PK] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cost](
    [Cost_PK] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Cost_Value] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Customer_FK] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Product_FK] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Cost] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Cost_PK] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cost]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK__Cost__Product_FK__5165187F] FOREIGN KEY([Product_FK])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Product] ([Product_PK])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cost] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__Cost__Product_FK__5165187F]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cost]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK__Cost__Customer_FK__5070F446] FOREIGN KEY([Customer_FK])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([Customer_PK])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cost] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__Cost__Customer_FK__5070F446]
GO
```

Comment: If you can create a SQL fiddle, or list a DDL statement to setup and insert some example data, that would help.

Comment: you get a -1 for not responding and not adding any sql

Comment: You get +1 for responding and adding SQL script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what you want to go into the `Cost`table is the value intersecting the Product column and Customer rows in the `Import`table and that the first column in the `Import`table is named `Customer_Name`, I think that what you is to unpivot the `Import`table.

If the number of products is fixed this query would do it:

```
SELECT Cost_Value, Customer.Customer_PK, Product.Product_PK
FROM 
   (SELECT Customer_Name, AProduct, BProduct, CProduct
   FROM Import) p
UNPIVOT
   (Cost_Value FOR Product_Name IN 
      (AProduct, BProduct, CProduct)
)AS unpvt
INNER JOIN Product ON unpvt.Product_Name=Product.Product_Name
INNER JOIN Customer ON unpvt.Customer_Name=Customer.Customer_Name;
```

But I would guess that you need a dynamic solution (adapting to a varying number of product columns in the Import table) and if so (and if the assumptions made above hold) the following query should work:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols =  STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Product_Name)
                FROM (
                    SELECT c.name AS Product_Name FROM sys.columns c
                    INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id 
                    WHERE t.name = 'Import' AND c.name != 'Customer_Name') x 
                ORDER BY Product_Name FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '  --INSERT Cost (Cost_Value,Customer_FK,Product_FK) 
                SELECT Cost_Value, c.Customer_PK, p.Product_PK
                FROM 
                    (SELECT Customer_Name, ' + @cols + ' FROM Import) p
                UNPIVOT
                    (Cost_Value FOR Product_Name IN (' + @cols + ')
                    ) AS unpvt
                INNER JOIN Product p ON unpvt.Product_Name = p.Product_Name
                INNER JOIN Customer c ON unpvt.Customer_Name = c.Customer_Name;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Given the sample data in your question this query would produce the following output (that could be inserted into `Cost` - I've commented out the insert in the query):

```
Cost_Value           Customer_PK Product_PK
-------------------- ----------- -----------
Sale Value1          1           1
Sale Value2          1           2
Sale Value3          1           3
Sale Value4          2           1
Sale Value5          2           2
Sale Value6          2           3
Sale Value7          3           1
Sale Value8          3           2
Sale Value9          3           3
```